# Recursively finding number of letter occurences in a string

Tags: java, string, indexing, char, substring

Hi im trying to create a recursive method that returns the amount of times a character exists within a word. So far I have created a method that achieves this non-recursively, but Im having trouble thinking about how to do it recursively.

```
public static int count (String line, char c)
{
     int charOccurences = 0;
     for (int x = 0 ; x < line.length () ; x++)
     {
         if (line.charAt (x) == c)
         {
             charOccurences++;
         }
     }
     return charOccurences;       
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Re think that recusion with the call `count("Hello World", 'o')`. Also put a println statement inside your `count` method. Like `System.out.println(line)`, Im sure you will take something away from it.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing some logic here.

- If you run out of characters 'c' then lastIndexOf returns -1 which will cause errors in the substring method.
- You need some logic to tally the occurrences of c.  Your recursion still has to add up the return values of your calls to 'count' or the number of times you call count.  Currently the last call to count is going to return 0 which will just get passed back.

This sounds like a homework problem so I'm going to let someone else do your homework for you :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ive edited my post with how i was able to do this normally. However I cant think of how i can achieve the same thing recursively. Could you give me an idea?

Comment: Your recursion before your edits was almost correct, you were just missing a few pieces of logic.  For a hint, consider: return count(line, c) + 1